# Well-ordered sets

Tags: set-theory

I would like to ask how many well-ordering of set $\mathbb N$ exist. And they shouldn't be isomorphic to each other. I found out that the set of well ordering of set $A$ is the subset of $A \times A$. And that the set can be always well-ordered, because it is enough to do an injection between these set and ordinal numbers. But how should I find out how many well-ordering of the set $\mathbb N$ exist? :))

Comment: Try to give your question a title that is descriptive. This will not only help you find other, similar questions which may already have an answer, but will also help other users know what your question is about before actually reading it.

Comment: Hello. Ok, thank you. I didn't know that the topis is the same but it is good for me too, because now I know much more answers :) Hi :)

Comment: And can I ask, here was the answer but it isn't here now. Would you know where can I find it? :)

Comment: Two answers on this page were deleted by their authors. Perhaps because they felt they did not address the actual question, or perhaps they felt that the duplicate should sufficiently answer your query.

Comment: I also don't know why you've edited your question to add a few empty lines at the bottom, but this is not something we expect people to do. Please don't do that in the future.

Comment: There was  written that there is a difference between the cardinality of all wel-ordering on the set $\mathbb N$ and between all isomorphic wel-ordering on the set $\mathbb N$ . A can't find in answers to topic Cardinality of order types in N too.

Comment: Ok I will try. It was a mistake. I was so happy that I have the answer to my question after long time spending finding answer. But then I helped my mum with her technical problems with computer and now I can't find out the answer. I don't understand it.

Comment: I read your materials which you added there Cardinality of order types in N (2 answers)
Ways of enumerating a countable set (2 answers) and it really helped me. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, $\mathbb{N}$ comes with a natural well-order, which is the usual $\leq$.

Let $(\mathbb{N}, R)$ be a well-ordered set. Then we have an associated ordinal $O(\mathbb{N}, R) \cong (\mathbb{N},R)$. Thus the associated ordinals must be countable.

Conversely, given a countable ordinal, we can lift an ordinal structure on $\mathbb{N}$.

Thus, the amount of (non-isomorphic) well-orders on $\mathbb{N}$ is the amount of countable infinite ordinals, which is $\aleph_1$ (the cardinality of the first uncountable ordinal).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me. :)

Comment: You might consider accepting it then :)

Comment: How do you thing?

Comment: Under the amount of upvotes (the 2 left next to my answer) there should be a button.

Comment: Of course ! Green button :)

Comment: Can I have one more question?

Comment: Of course. Go ahead.

Comment: We didn't do associated ordinals so why the amount of (non-isomorphic) well-orders on N is the amount of countable infinite ordinals? Is there some more intuitive answer?

Comment: I understand the conclusion but how will we know that?

Comment: Well you can show that every well-ordered set is order-isomorphic to a unique ordinal. This takes some work to prove. That's essentially what my answer uses. This correspondence allows us to translate "well-orders" into "ordinals" and for ordinals the question is easier to answer. You can think of ordinals as "well-order" - types.

Comment: You are so good! thanks.For example {2,3,4,.....1} corresponds to $\omega+1$. Because of property of sum of sell-ordered sets.

Comment: Or {3,4,5,.....,1,2} to $\omega + 2

Comment: Yes, basically that's true.

Comment: Or {X, Y} where X are odd and Y are even to $\omega+\omega$

Comment: Or {Y, X} where X are odd and Y are even to $\omega+\omega$  ??

Comment: Then there aren't unique :(

Comment: Well, there are some subtleties. You have to put an order on these sets first.

Comment: But yeah, $\omega+\omega$ can be thought of as two disjoint copies of $\mathbb{N}$, one placed after the other.

Comment: Not unique because they aren't ordinals.

Comment: $\{3,4,5, \dots, 1,2\}$ for example is not an ordinal. Any ordinal contains $\emptyset = 0$.

Comment: So ${3,4,5,.......0,1,2}$ is an ordilan $\omega+3$. An it is the well ordering of the set $\mathbb N$.

Comment: No is not an ordinal. An ordinal is a set of elements. As a set, what you wrote is $\{0,1,2, \dots\}= \omega$

Comment: So should I write it as a set {3,4,5,.......0,1,2} and it will be an ordinal $\omega + 3$?

Comment: Or there is a problem with a construction?

Comment: So I should erite {3,4,5,....} $\union$ {0,1,2}, where {3,4,5,....} and {0,1,2} are well-ordered sets? :)Then the ordinal of these union is $\omega+3$.

Comment: I think that now I am littlebit prepared to a test. I am really grateful for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point:

Take the well-ordering $\preceq$  on $\mathbb N$ defined by

$a\preceq b \text{ if } \begin{cases}\text{$a$ is even and $b$ is odd}\\a\leq b \text{ where $a$ and $b$ both odd}\\ a\leq b \text{ where $a$ and $b$ both even}\end{cases}$

In effect this takes the standard well-ordering on the even natural numbers and the standard ordering on the odd natural numbers, and puts one before the other.

This is a well-ordering but is not order-isomorphic to the standard ordering $\leq$ since the number $1$ has infinitely many values less than it.

Comment: Thank you, you answered to my another question, find two well-ordering of the set $\mathbb N$ which aren't isomorphic and don't have got the largest element :)